# jQuery action works when bound to mouse but not when bound to a click

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm a super long time reader but have made few comments around here. Every other time I've had a question, I've been able to search for the answer before I had to actually ask anything. I try to be good at not being lazy.

Anyway, I've been teaching myself more jQuery lately and I've run into a problem that I can't just search for. More educated eyes than mine are needed. Please note that this isn't fully compatible with Internet Exploder yet (conversation for another thread)

In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29Aat/65/

I have the mouse scroll bound to an up & down effect on a curtain from the bottom. It works well enough for my purposes. Scroll down, main content shows. Scroll up, welcome screen shows.

Aside: Don't try to open this in mobile resolution yet... I haven't finished setting it up. Suffice to say, there won't be a bunch of layers flying around.

So I have two main functions for raising and lowering the blinds.

`showit()`
`hideit()`

```
// Function to show #main-content in standard resolution
function showit() {
    if ($('#main-content').hasClass('hideit')) {
        $('#main-content').removeClass('hideit').addClass('showit');
        $('#wrap').removeClass('cursor');
        $('#main-content').stop().animate({
            height: '+=' + realheight,
            opacity: 0.7
        });
        $('#welcome').stop().animate({
            opacity: 0,
            top: '-=10'
        }, 600).delay(400).animate({
            top: midpoint
        }, 100);
    }
}

// Function to hide #main-content in standard resolution
function hideit() {
    if ($('#main-content').hasClass('showit')) {
        $('#main-content').removeClass('showit').addClass('hideit');
        $('#wrap').addClass('cursor');
        $('#main-content').stop().animate({
            height: '-=' + realheight,
            opacity: 0
        });
        $('#welcome').stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
            top: '+=10'
        }, 600);
    }
}
```

When the mouse scroll calls `hideit()` the curtain drops perfectly.

When I click on the red <kbd>X</kbd> to call `hideit()` - top right corner on main content curtain - it doesn't execute properly. Instead of the curtain going down, it shoots up again.

Hoping someone here can help explain that. I'm at my wits end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is propagation. The `.closeit` button is inside `#wrap`. This means that when you click on the red X, the `hideit` function will run correctly, but the click event will propagate and eventually reach `#wrap` which will also handle it, running `showit` - resulting in the strange effect you see.

You need to stop propagation using the `event.stopPropagation()` method in the close button's event handler like this:

```
// Activate the close button
$(".closeit").click(function (e) {
    hideit();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29Aat/66/) (also disarmed the mobile stuff, so I could view it properly)

Comment: Ok that should have been the most obvious thing on earth. Wow. Thank you! Now to go about re-working things :)

Comment: Right, and thank you for the fixed fiddle. Nice of you; no need to rework a thing :)

Comment: Quick question Baz... should I re-post to ask about the events not firing in IE or is it something you can give me a hint on here? I know it's something simple because I almost accidentally made it work between updates then wiped out my fix and I'm baffled as to what it may have been.

Comment: @Imperative You should ask a new question about it, but first try to narrow down the problem. Remove clutter and try to find the problematic parts.

Comment: Turned out the issue was that the scroll binds were centering on the welcome text itself in IE. If the text wasn't hovered, no bind was firing.